# confusion about how to use c++ reference

Tags: c++

I am new to C++, I got confused about the c++ reference, for example, the [std::map::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) reference, at the beginning, it has :

```
pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);
template <class P> pair<iterator,bool> insert (P&& val);    
iterator insert (const_iterator position, const value_type& val);
template <class P> iterator insert (const_iterator position, P&& val);
template <class InputIterator>
void insert (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);  
void insert (initializer_list<value_type> il);
```

In the later example, it uses the insert like this:

```
mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',200) );
```

From which line of the reference can I know that I can use the `insert` function as above?

Comment: If you look a bit down at the description for `val`, *Member type value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in map as pair<const key_type,mapped_type>*

Comment: @chris thank you, didn't read that line ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `std::map<char,int>`, the line

```
mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,int>('z',200) );
```

is allowed since map defines the single element constructor

```
single element (1)  
pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);
template <class P> pair<iterator,bool> insert (P&& val);
```

the second one should kick in if you're using C++11. In C++03 only the first one is available.

The documentation says

```
Member type value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in map as 
pair<const key_type,mapped_type>
```

thus `std::pair<char,int>` is the `value_type` of your map and the insertion is valid (a temporary can bind to a lvalue const reference or rvalue references in C++11).

I'm not suggesting to also take a look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) since it might be even less understandable if you had problems with cplusplus.com, but generally I would recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

`std::pair<char const, int>` is the `value_type` of `mymap`. The first `insert` overload you quoted takes a `const`-reference to `value_type`.

Using a standard library reference requires basic knowledge of the language and corresponding library parts. Looking up a member function without understanding of the class it is a member of will, in most of the cases, not work out well. If you have a look at the reference for map you'll see that `value_type` is defined as `pair<const key_type, mapped_type>` which fits here since `pair<char, int>` is convertible to `pair<char const, int>` -- you also need to know how `pair` works.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the **Parameters** section on the same page below, you will find the following description for `val`:

`Value to be copied to (or moved as) the inserted element.
Member type value_type is the type of the elements in the container, defined in map as pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`

which clearly states that `value_type` is the type of the elements in the container, defined in `map` as `pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`